# How can i display 2 different buttons in a 2 different textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

[it is my html code the structure of my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bhkY.png)

i found a youtube content wherein he is creating a calculator but he only use 2 textbox, in my case i want to use 3 text box, i want the first number to display at textbox 1, i want to display second number at textbox 2 and their result will be displayed at textbox 3

```js
 function getNumber(num){
 var input_var = document.getElementById('num1');
 switch(num){
  case 1:
   input_var.value +='1';
   break;
  case 2:
   input_var.value +='2';
   break;
  case 3:
   input_var.value +='3';
   break;
  case 4:
   input_var.value +='4';
   break;
  case 5:
   input_var.value +='5';
   break;
  case 6:
   input_var.value +='6';
   break;
  case 7:
   input_var.value +='7';
   break;
  case 8:
   input_var.value +='8';
   break;
  case 9:
   input_var.value +='9';
   break;
  case 10:
   input_var.value +='0';
   break;
 }
}

function getOperand(operand){
 var input_var = document.getElementById('answer');
 switch(operand){
  case '+':
   input_var.value +='+';
   break;
  case '-':
   input_var.value +='-';
   break;
  case 'x':
   input_var.value +='*';
   break;
  case '/':
   input_var.value +='/'
   break;
  case '+/-':
   input_var.value +='-'+input_var.value;

  }
 }

function clearScreen(){

 document.getElementById('answer').value = "";
 }

 function backspace(){
 var input_var = document.getElementById('answer');
 var x = input_var.value;
 if (x.length > 0){
  x = x.substring(0,x.length-1);
  input_var.value = x;
 }
}

function compute(){
 var input_var = document.getElementById('answer');
 ans = +eval(input_var.value);
 document.getElementById('answer').value="= "+ans; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Simple Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
 <table>
  <tr>
   </tr>
    <td class="heading">
     Simple Math Calculator
    </td>
    <tr>
   </tr>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="num1" style="text-align: right;"><br>
    <input type="text" id="num2" style="text-align: right;"><br>
    <input type="text" id="answer" readonly="readonly" style="color: green; text-align: right;" placeholder="0">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <td>
   <input type="button" value="CE" onclick="clearScreen()" style="color: white; background: red;">
   <input type="button" value="&#247;" onclick="getOperand('/')">
   <input type="button" value="x" onclick="getOperand('x')">
   <input type="button" value="&#8592;" onclick="backspace()" style="color: red;">
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="1" onclick="getNumber(1)">
   <input type="button" value="2" onclick="getNumber(2)">
   <input type="button" value="3" onclick="getNumber(3)">
   <input type="button" value="+" onclick="getOperand('+')">
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="4" onclick="getNumber(4)">
   <input type="button" value="5" onclick="getNumber(5)">
   <input type="button" value="6" onclick="getNumber(6)">
   <input type="button" value="-" onclick="getOperand('-')">
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="7" onclick="getNumber(7)">
   <input type="button" value="8" onclick="getNumber(8)">
   <input type="button" value="9" onclick="getNumber(9)">
   <input type="button" value="+/-" onclick="getOperand('+/-')">
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="0" onclick="getNumber(0)">
   <input type="button" value="=" onclick="compute()" style="width: 120px; color: white; background: green;">
   <br>





  </td>  
 </table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```